# What is reform's rationale for validation not being in models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, reform

The reform gem advocates not having validations within models. Instead, it advocates them being in the form.

> Validations From Models
>
> ...
>
> Sometimes when you still keep validations in your models (which you
>   shouldn't) copying them to a form might not feel right. In that case,
>   you can let Reform automatically copy them.
>
> ...
>
> Be warned that we do not encourage copying validations. You should
>   rather move validation code into forms and not work on your model
>   directly anymore.

What rationale does the reform gem project, or its authors, give for not having validation in models?

Answer (score 3):

I would split validations into two different categories:

- Data Integrity
- Business Logic

**Data integrity** means the model can't be used without meeting certain criteria. You need to ensure the model will never be considered valid in this state. 
Most of the time however this concerns things such as unicity which are persistence related. So these constraints would better be enforced at the database level rather than in the model.

**Business Logic** on the other hand is directly related to the functional needs of the application.

Let's take an example: When a user signs up I only want him to fill his *e-mail* but when he edits his profile I want to make sure he also fills in his *first name* and *last name*.

Considering validations belong to the model, you need to start cluttering it with conditional validations. Here you would check before validating if the model was persisted already or not and this would do the trick. But add more forms with different requirements and this quickly becomes an hell to manage.

That is because the validation logic depends on the context of the application (the form being filled by the user, the API endpoint being called ...). You want to validate that the parameters required by this application context are valid, not the model state.

Things become a lot more easy and maintainable if you set-up different sets of validation for each context. This leads to a bit more code to write but a lot cleaner and maintainable logic.